# LAMP server time out

Tags: server, apache2, php, connection

I have a LAMP server (no M since I don't have a need for a database) where I am posting pictures to the server using PHP. Everything is working fine and then all of a sudden my devices can no longer connect to the server. When I issue a reboot command (through SSH as I'm still able to connect that way) the units can successfully post again, for a given amount of time (not yet determined - hopefully later today/this weekend). This is a regular occurrence for 3 units posting to the server (these are Arduino driven ESP32-CAM units).

Since I'm a noob to LAMP server, I'm struggling with the terms to use for searches as everything with "connect" in the search references SSH. I did try and turn off any sort of sleep timers, using:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

but that didn't seem to help. Any suggestions for additional troubleshooting you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your server is going to sleep? If you can still SSH in, this points to an issue with Apache, such as running out of memory or having too many threads open. Is there anything in `/var/log/apache/error.log` that might point to the source of the problem?

Comment: @matigo, thanks for the reference to the logs. That lead me down a path where I found it to be a DNS issue as I was using the DNS name of the server in my Arduino code. When I changed to the IP Address instead of DNS name, the problem went away. Thanks a bunch!